# Why QlistWidget method indexesMoved doesn't send a signal?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside6, qlistwidget

I activated Drag and Drop mode for my QlistWidget, so I need to catch a signal from IndexesMoved to rewrite changes in settings file. But when items moved, the event handler doesn't call my function. I can't understand why? I thought every widget got an index when it added into widgetlist, but I guess they don't. So if there are no indexes, nothing have to change.
This is my code ....

```
import json
import os.path

from PySide6.QtCore import QSize, QRect
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QGroupBox, QPushButton, QWidget, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem, QAbstractItemView

from windows import ClientCreationWindow
from windows.custom_wigets import ClientListWidget


class ChooseClientWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ChooseClientWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('app name')
        self.clients_group_box = QGroupBox(self)
        self.clients_group_box.setObjectName(u'clients_group_box')
        self.clients_list = QListWidget(self.clients_group_box)
        self.clients_list.setObjectName(u'clients_list')
        self.custom_widgets_dict = None
        self.add_button = QPushButton(self.clients_group_box)
        self.add_button.setObjectName(u'add_button')
        self.del_button = QPushButton(self.clients_group_box)
        self.del_button.setObjectName(u'del_button')
        self.choose_button = QPushButton(self.clients_group_box)
        self.choose_button.setObjectName(u'choose_button')
        # MainWindow object
        self.create_client_window = None
        self.geometry_init()

    def geometry_init(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(390, 190))
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(390, 190))
        self.group_boxes_init()
        self.lists_init()
        self.buttons_init()

    def group_boxes_init(self):
        self.clients_group_box.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 370, 160))
        self.clients_group_box.setTitle('Connections')

    def buttons_init(self):
        self.add_button.setGeometry(QRect(250, 30, 110, 30))
        self.add_button.setText('Create')
        self.add_button.clicked.connect(self.add_client)

        self.del_button.setGeometry(QRect(250, 70, 110, 30))
        self.del_button.setText('Delete')
        self.del_button.clicked.connect(self.delete_client)

        self.choose_button.setGeometry(QRect(250, 110, 110, 30))
        self.choose_button.setText('Choose')
        self.choose_button.clicked.connect(self.choose_client)

    def lists_init(self):
        self.clients_list.setGeometry(QRect(10, 30, 230, 120))

        # code that fills list

        self.clients_list.doubleClicked.connect(self.choose_client)
        self.clients_list.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.clients_list.indexesMoved.connect(self.widget_position_changed)

    def widget_position_changed(self):
        settings: dict[int, str] = {}
        for index, widget in enumerate(self.clients_list.items(ClientListWidget)):
            settings[index] = widget.name_label.text()
        json.dump(settings, open('settings.txt', 'w'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You misinterpreted the documentation about [`indexesMoved`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistview.html#indexesMoved):

> This signal is emitted when the specified indexes are moved **in the view**.

<sup>*(emphasis mine)*</sup>

While the normal usage of QListView (from which QListWidget directly inherits) is to vertically *display* (the *visual* order) items in the same order they are *in the model* (the *logical* order), its primary purpose is just to show objects that are part of a *mono dimensional* list.

This is a common misconception: how items are *visually* shown in a view is completely arbitrary, and only depends on how the view is implemented. The *model* (what contains the actual logical order) is what actually matters. Remember that QListWidget (like QTableWidget and QTreeWidget) is just a higher level implementation of a view that "embeds" a model: in these higher level classes, models and views are quite interconnected, but the underlying [Qt model/view concepts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html) remain.

In the case of QListView, it's just its default behavior that shows those items visually like they are logically ordered, but that's it; this is clearly explained [in its documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistview.html#details): in fact, items can be shown in very different ways in a QListView, such as a grid or any arbitrary order, just like an "icon view"; think about file managers: while they allow moving the icons around, their visual position won't change their "order" in the file system. In fact, Qt uses QListView in icon mode when showing non-native QFileDialogs.

Properties like [`viewMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#viewMode-prop) and [`movement`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistview.html#movement-prop) will make drag and drop feature only work for *visual* display and will **never** affect the logical order.

So, that signal has absolutely nothing to do with reordering, but it's only related to the *visible* position of items in the view: when the user moves an item (such as an icon representing a file) in a different position within the view. When that happens, the *logical* order of items is unchanged, only the *visual* one is. Fundamentally speaking, it's just like dragging the sections in a header of a QTableView: doing it won't change the order of the rows or columns in the model, just their *visual* position (that's why QHeaderView provides functions like [`logicalIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qheaderview.html#logicalIndex) and [`visualIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qheaderview.html#visualIndex)).

If you need to keep track of changes in the *logical* order of items, then you need to check that against the *model*, not the view: in this specific case, you need to connect to the [`rowsMoved`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsMoved) signal:

```py
class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.view = QListWidget()
        self.view.setDragDropMode(
            QAbstractItemView.DragDropMode.InternalMove)
        self.view.addItems(('a', 'b', 'c'))

        self.addBtn = QPushButton('Add items')

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.addWidget(self.addBtn)

        self.view.model().rowsMoved.connect(self.rowsMoved)
        self.addBtn.clicked.connect(self.add)

    def add(self):
        self.view.addItem(
            'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[self.view.count() % 26])

    def rowsMoved(self, parent, first, last, dest, target):
        print('row {} was moved to {}'.format(first, target))
```

Note that the `target` argument is the insertion index **before** the selected item has been moved.

If you have `a`, `b` and `c` and you want to move `a` *after* `b`, the `target` will be `2`, not `1`, because that's the position after b before any movement was applied.

If you rebuild the json data from scratch every time, that is not a problem, as you can completely ignore the arguments, but in case you need to keep persistent ordering outside of the list widget, you must always consider that when an item is moved *after* its position.

Practically, this means that movements in a model are done by "inserting" the item in the new position **before** removing it from the old.

Finally, you should *really* use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/layout.html).